# How do I stop sitemap.xml displaying instead of the /sitemap/index.php template?

Tags: templates

I have a template_group/template like sitemap/index.php, in which I have a regular html site map for site visitors. I also have sitemap.xml in the root folder.

visiting www.site.com/sitemap is showing the sitemap.xml file and not the one I have in sitemap/index.php.

I'm using the EL supplied htacccess file to remove index.php from url's.

Be grateful for any suggestions on how to fix this please.

Best wishes
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guy's! In the end i went super simple and just renamed my xml file to site-map.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I would move your sitemap.xml file to an EE template make sure you choose xml as the template type. Then remove your sitemap.xml from the root.

YOu can update your xml sitemap url in google webmasters tool and set up an .htaccess 301 redirect to ensure there are no problems with the move.

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that the forward slash is appended to `www.site.com/sitemap/` this will tell EE that it is a directory rather than a file and it will go hunting for the index.php file in that directory.

You can also try to specifically set the headers for XML files in the .htaccess file to be sure:

```
# Set encoding for file extensions
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType application/xml .xml
  AddType text/xml .xml .xsl .xsf .xsd
</IfModule>
```